# still confused about cardinality

Tags: database, database-design, cardinality

after watching some tutorials, I feel like I am still confused about cardinality when it comes to `one to many` and `many to many` relationship. I am trying to practice a little example here, I know my design is wrong when it comes to cardinality, what would be the correct relationship between these entities ?? I get confused when I have 3 table relationship like `FilmPeople` and `FilmGenre`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships look right. There are some problems though.

1. Naming convention: You should name `People` table as `Person` because you don't have plural naming anywhere else.
2. Name `FilmDirector` table as `Director`. See next point for why. Once you do that `Director` table should not have `film_ID` column.
3. Your model has a mixture of logical and physical model. Let me explain. Relationship between `FilmDirector` and `Film` is a logical many-to-many relationship. When that relationship is physically created in a database it goes through `Film`->`FilmDirector` and `Director`->`FilmDirector` tables with `Film` to `FilmDirector` one-to-many and `Director` to `FilmDirector` one-to-many relationships. `FilmDirector` table connects `Film` and `Director`  tables to establish many-to-many relationship. Therefore I suggest naming your `FilmDirector` table as `Director` so that the connection table can be correctly named as `FilmDirector`. Such a connection table is needed in many-to-many relationship because it is not possible to put multiple values of foreign key references in one table row. Entries go in the connection table for every row in one table being related to multiple rows in other table. In this example for relating one `Film` with multiple `Director`s we make multiple entries in `FilmDirector` table. Similarly for relating one `Director` with multiple `Film`s we make entries in `FilmDirector` table.
4. Relationship you have shown between `Film`, `FilmGenre` and `Genre` is a physical many-to-many between `Film` and `Genre`. If your model is a logical model you should not show this as a 3 table relationship. If the model is a physical model you should show `Film` and `Director` many-to-many as a 3 table relationship. So, decide whether you want to show physical model or logical model and change your model accordingly.

Hope my explanation is clear enough!

Comment: you said filmDirector table as Director , so what if Film (meaning the film itself) has to be directed by one or more directors ? would I still have not have FilmDirector and Film...thats why I put it there

Comment: edit: yes I was thinking Film with multiple Directors or just one

Comment: thank you so much!...I went over this one more, I'm glad you told me the difference between logical and physical many to many relationship..wish I could give you 10 likes